# Custom crafts in the Stonecutter are not appearing in the correct order

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

For the past few days, I've been trying to create a plugin that allows crafting custom mob heads using the Stonecutter. I finally managed to get something functional, but when I select one type of head, it gives me a different one instead.

[stonecutter craft bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtVlS.png)

Here is my code:

```
package me.zoteuh.grillade;

import com.mojang.authlib.GameProfile;
import com.mojang.authlib.properties.Property;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.NamespacedKey;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.RecipeChoice;
import org.bukkit.inventory.StonecuttingRecipe;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.SkullMeta;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import static org.bukkit.Bukkit.getServer;

public class CustomHeads {

    public static void loadCustomHeads(Grillade pluginInstance) {

        List<ItemStack> headMaterials = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                new ItemStack(Material.SKELETON_SKULL),
                new ItemStack(Material.ZOMBIE_HEAD),
                new ItemStack(Material.CREEPER_HEAD),
                new ItemStack(Material.PIGLIN_HEAD)
        ));

        RecipeChoice material = new RecipeChoice.ExactChoice(headMaterials);

        File jsonFile = new File(pluginInstance.getDataFolder(), "heads.json");

        if (jsonFile.exists()) {
            try {
                JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
                JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader(jsonFile));

                for (Object obj : jsonArray) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
                    String name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
                    String texture = (String) jsonObject.get("texture");

                    getLogger().info("Name: " + name);
                    getLogger().info("Texture: " + texture);

                    String recipeID = "custom_head_recipe_" + name;
                    NamespacedKey recipeKey = new NamespacedKey(pluginInstance, recipeID.toLowerCase());

                    ItemStack customHead = createCustomHead(texture, name);
                    StonecuttingRecipe headRecipe = createRecipe(material, customHead, recipeKey);
                    getServer().addRecipe(headRecipe);
                }
            } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
                getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "Error reading heads.json or creating recipes.", e);
            }
        } else {
            getLogger().warning("heads.json file not found.");
        }
    }

    private static ItemStack createCustomHead(String texture, String name) {
        ItemStack skull = new ItemStack(Material.PLAYER_HEAD);
        SkullMeta skullMeta = (SkullMeta) skull.getItemMeta();

        if (applyTextureToSkull(skullMeta, texture)) {
            skullMeta.setDisplayName(name);
            skull.setItemMeta(skullMeta);
            return skull;
        } else {
            getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "Erreur lors de l'application de la texture au crâne.");
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static boolean applyTextureToSkull(SkullMeta skullMeta, String texture) {
        GameProfile profile = new GameProfile(UUID.randomUUID(), null);
        profile.getProperties().put("textures", new Property("textures", texture));

        try {
            Field profileField = skullMeta.getClass().getDeclaredField("profile");
            profileField.setAccessible(true);
            profileField.set(skullMeta, profile);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "Erreur lors de l'application de la texture au crâne.", e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static StonecuttingRecipe createRecipe(RecipeChoice skullMaterial, ItemStack customHead, NamespacedKey recipeKey) {
        return new StonecuttingRecipe(
                recipeKey,
                customHead,
                skullMaterial
        );
    }

    private static Logger getLogger() {
        return Logger.getLogger("CustomHeads");
    }
}
```

And here is my JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "name": "test",
    "texture": "eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvNjNmZTU5YjJhMWQyYmYzMjcwNDA2OGVmYzg2MGM3NWY5MjEyYzIzMTBiNDNkMDdjNGJiYTRiNGViMjM0ZTY4NCJ9fX0="
  },
  {
    "name": "cake",
    "texture": "eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvZWZlMDJmZDViNGM2NTI2MDg1Y2JkZjNlZTM1ZDE4ZDA3ZDUxYTY3MjVmZTU0MTdhZDVhZDdmNDdkYmExYzVlIn19fQ=="
  },
  {
    "name": "beer",
    "texture": "eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvNDA1M2UyNjg2N2JiNTc1MzhlOTc4OTEzN2RiYmI1Mzc3NGUxOGVkYTZmZWY1MWNiMmVkZjQyNmIzNzI2NCJ9fX0="
  },
  {
    "name": "mailbox",
    "texture": "eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvMzQ1ZmQxNzRmMjUwMzdiN2Y5ZWNhNzMzY2ZkMDQ2YThiNjM1MTEyMDI2NDg1MzcwNWJjYWE1YjYzZTE3YzE3In19fQ=="
  },
  {
    "name": "books",
    "texture": "eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvNDIxN2ZkYTI5YzUwYzkzN2VhOTViYjk5ODI4MzY0YTVhMTViZGFjZWI4ZjNhOGJlMDg4ZGYwYTUxZjYxN2JjNCJ9fX0="
  }
]
```

I've understood the issue, but I'm unsure how to resolve it. I have 5 heads in my JSON file: "test," "cake," "beer," "mailbox," and "books." Since I'm importing them from top to bottom, they should appear in this order: "books," "mailbox," "beer," "cake," "test." The problem is that in the selection menu of the stonecutter, they are appearing out of order. What's strange is that even though they are in the wrong order, if I select the first head that displays "mailbox," it does indeed suggest crafting the "books" head. The crafting process works correctly; if I select head 1, it crafts head 1. The issue appears to be a display problem that is not showing the heads in the correct order in the selection menu.

Comment: Are you reloading or restarting your server between each test of your plugin ? Maybe it's an issue with data from a previous test that are still registered into the server